# Checkbox can not checked when added dynamically in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am creating html table dynamically. Having label and checkbox in each row.
Table is being created successfully, but the checkbox are not getting checked or unchecked.

I want the whole html code as a string to use it in another function to display table in modal popup

Here is the code...

```
$("#btnActivate").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/configuration/getConfiguredSmartCrind",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (response) {
                var result = JSON.parse(response);


                var str = "<div class='table-responsive' style='width:100%;'><table id='activateConfigurationTable' class='table  fc-style'><thead><tr><th style='width:50%;'>SmartCRIND Id</th><th style='width:50%;'>Status</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    str += "<tr id='" + result[i] + "'><td>" + result[i] + "</td><td><input type='checkbox' id='chk" + result[i] + "' name='check'  value='check" + result[i] + "'/></td></tr>";


                }
                str += "</tbody></table></div>";                   

                confirmOkModal(str, "activateConfiguration();", "", 'Continue', 'Abort');
            },
            error: function (textstatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error occurred');
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: value="check" doesnot make checkbox checked you have to add prperty checked to checkbox

Comment: what do you mean by "checkbox are not getting checked or unchecked"? Either you are not getting checkbox value in js or check box is not working?

Comment: `str += "<tr id='" + result[i] + "'><td>" + result[i] + "</td><td><input type='checkbox' id='chk" + result[i] + "' name='check'  value='check" + result[i] + "' checked /></td></tr>"`

Comment: If they're not getting checked or unchecked, what is happening to them?

Comment: Checkbox not getting checked means, nothing happens when I click on checkbox. No check, uncheck happening on checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

confirmOkModal in my code is a **bootstrap modal**. That's why checkbox is not working.

In this case Two events seems to obsolete each other. I have to overcome bootstrap modals e.preventDefault() in click events.

used => **e.stopImmediatePropagation();** in checkbox click event.

Checkbox is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to getting checked a checkbox just add `checked` before end tag like `<input type="checkbox" checked/>`